# Cannot execute PHP file from domain name

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost, php-fpm

Server run on Amazon Linux AMI** (similary to redhat)
I follow the installation from [Install PHP-FPM, Nginx, & MySQL on EC2 with Amazon Linux AMI](http://www.codingsteps.com/install-php-fpm-nginx-mysql-on-ec2-with-amazon-linux-ami/)

It's work properly if I call directly from server IP address like `174.129.213.152/index.php` 
and I can access other file from my domain correctly like `http://gamebiz.asia/robots.txt` 

The problem is when I call php file `http://gamebiz.asia` or `http://gamebiz.asia/index.php` their result in blank page.

 I try change configuration from

`fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;` and `fastcgi_pass    localhost:9000;`

the result when I call php file is "502 Bad Gateway" and If I remove `fastcgi_pass` I got "download" file instead of execute php file

## **Configuration**

### conf.d/default.conf

```
server{
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|mp3|ogg|wav|aac)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           max;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    server_tokens off;
}
```

### sites-available/gamebiz.asia.conf

```
server {
    server_name  www.gamebiz.asia;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://gamebiz.asia$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gamebiz.asia;
    root   /var/www/html/SpotDiff/Release;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I try config virtual host and sub-domain follow [Installing NGINX and PHP-FPM - Setup for NGINX](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-nginx-and-php-fpm-setup-for-nginx)

they said I need to setup the different UNIX Sockets for PHP-FPM in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/` 
Unfortunately Amazon Linux AMI don't have apt-get and I don't have directory `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/` and I search for `pool.d` but don't know how to get this file and directory. 
I end up on change `fastcgi_pass` from `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/DOMAINNAME.socket;` to my default `unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;` but still got blank page

Please help me I struggle with this for 3 whole days. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: try adding  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name; to sites-available/gamebiz.asia.conf in php location block

Comment: sorry I can't change that for now because now my php-fpm config is broken too. Thank so much.

Comment: great!!! it's work thank you so much so much sooo muchhhhh~~.
please answer and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing

```
 fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
```

from the config of server_name gamebiz.asia; config block.